# Access data from Google Analytics Conversion Tracking Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, google-analytics

I have a JS script included on a website that I dont have access to be able to change the content on the page, but i need to track conversions.

Now the site already uses google analytics, so I am looking to re-use the google conversion tracking if this is possible

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];    
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_addTrans', '001', 'Store', '1.2', '0.0000', '1.0', 'City', '', 'GB']);
_gaq.push(['_addItem', '001', 'my-sku', 'Product Name', '', '0.80', '1.000']);
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);
```

I tried accessing the _gaq array, but it looks to clear out the lines once they are processed.
Has anyone any idea, how i can get this data into a usable format, possibly by using regex on the page maybe?

Thanks